# Initialize custom properties in main class from referenced project in C# using custom attribute

Tags: c#

I'm creating a NuGet package that has [FromReference("someKey")] property attribute. I need to fill in the values of these properties (based on FromReference key) in projects that use my package.

Here's a sample of what I'd like to achieve

```cs
public static class UserClass {

   [FromReference("MyAppSecret")] 
   public static string PublicAttributeProp { get; set; }

}
```

Here `FromReference` belongs to my NuGet package while the UserClass is a separate project having a dependency on the package.

So how do I set the PublicAttributeProp with a certain value from my Nuget package on load of the Assembly that holds the UserClass?

Comment: Are you the one who will instantiate the object containing the property the have that attribute ?
Otherwise I'm not sure it will be possible without playing with some code generation (like Postsharp).

Comment: No, this package could be used by anyone. So I see there's no workaround for it! Thanks!